# 405 Method not allowed using Restler

Tags: php, api, post, restler

I have a problem with Restler: I'm creating my own API to access my data from differente website. When I try to send a POST request to my API, it says:

```
{
    error: {
        code: 405
        message: "Method Not Allowed"
    }
    debug: {
        source: "Routes.php:422 at route stage"
        stages: {
            success: [1]
                0:  "get"

            failure: [3]
                0:  "route"
                1:  "negotiate"
                2:  "message"
        }
    }
}
```

My index.php code is:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('v1'); // repeat for more
$r->handle(); //serve the response
```

I have already tried to put:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
```

but nothing. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order Restler to accept POST requests, post function has to be implemented your **v1 class**.

A typical example can be:

```
function post($request_data = NULL){
   $result = new stdClass();
   $result->sometitle = 'OK';
   return $result;
}
```

where `$request_data` is the Array with your passed POST parameters.

This function will be accessed only on POST method and it will return:

```
{
  "sometitle ": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D Now I can pass data via POST